# sqlite3: Select rowid with SQLiteDatbase instance

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way for selecting the rowid from table using SQLiteDatabase instance

```
Cursor websiteCursor= mDatabaseManipulator.query(mTableName, null, COLUMN_WEBSITENAME+"='"+websiteName+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

Above cursor doesn't get the rowid. The doc says passing null in second argument will return all columns. But rowid is not returned.

I m getting rowid using rawQuery.

```
Cursor websiteCursor = mDatabaseManipulator.rawQuery("Select rowid _id, * from " + mTableName + " where " + COLUMN_WEBSITENAME + " = '" + websiteName +"'", null);
```

Comment: How do you know the rowid is not returned? Note that `rowid` is just an alias for the `integer primary key` column if there's one.

Comment: In your raw query, you do not get the rowid with *  but have to list it explicitly, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem in the way that you are implementing the cursor, try this :-

```
Cursor websiteCursor= mDatabaseManipulator.query(mTableName, new String[]{rowid_id}, COLUMN_WEBSITENAME+" =? ", new String[]{websiteName}, null, null, null);
```